# Printer stops extruding at same point on each pass

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, extrusion, thermal-runaway

### Issue:

I realized that the filament extrusion always stops at the same spot for a couple seconds then starts back, I know it's the printer and not the filament, I can see the gear literally stop for a couple seconds. The fan also stops during that time,  I suspect it has caused the printer to activate it's thermal runaway protection shutdown a couple times. I have no idea what to google to fix it. Here is a picture:

[image: Filament gap]

As you can see it's like it stops before the curve, but to be clear, unlike all the questions I have read here, it starts back a couple seconds after.

### For context:

- Printer: Ender S1 Pro
- Slicer: Cura 5.2.2

### Maybe related?

I've had my printer for maybe 2 months, and I thought I finally had it setup, prints were consistent and never failing, then yesterday it's like every single setting fell apart at the same time.

The print is no longer sticking to the bed, and I constantly get a "AB Temp." shutdown. I switched the nozzle, no success. I always level it with a sheet of paper, but now I see that after the bed probe hits (as it does before every print), it causes it to raise the nozzle a couple tenth of a millimeter, which explains why it's not sticking. I fixed that by changing the Z-Index, but it's weird that it randomly changed? (by 0.3mm which is significant)

I have no idea how to fix the extrusion stopping randomly though, but I think when the extrusion and fan stop together, it suddenly changes the nozzle thermal properties, so its temperature shoots up, I think that's what's causing the "AB Temp." shutdown.

I print via USB-C so it's not a corrupt file, I have been printing this way many times, no issues. I'm stumped, thank you for your help!

### Update:

This time I got quite far before thermal shutdown, it doesn't look random so I think the problem might be in the G-Code, at the same time, I don't get the pattern. Here are the pictures:
[image: Gap on surface][image: Gap on brim]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you encounter is related to a partly broken wire or problem with the seating of connector plugs in their sockets. The fact that the fan also stops hints to this. You need to check all cables and connectors, especially the thermistor.

Such problems arise after a few months of usage.

Comment: I checked the wires and the thermistor already, if you look at the pattern of when the extrusion stops (1st picture of the update) you can trace imaginary lines on the print (8) where the extrusion state changes, and you see that it the state only changes on those lines. Imo this is way too regular to hint at a lose wire, or any random issue for that matter. I would bet my hand the issue is in the logic somehow.

Comment: AB Temp errors are related to the cables and the connections, there are numerous of these problems posted, all resolved with a new cable.

Comment: I changed the printer's power outlet because I read somewhere that it can be caused by power issues (it was on a power bar with many other appliances), and now with its own outlet and printing from SD card, the issue is not there. I'll keep on troubleshooting to see if the outlet fixed it or the SD card.

Comment: In the end it was indeed the cable, the temperature reading cable in the ribbon wire to be specific. I replaced it and the AB temp never came back. The fan and extrusion problems were side effects I think, because when the printer thought the temperature dropped it stopped extruding and stopped the fan, but all those features were working normally.

Comment: Very nice to come back, vote and comment, all the best with printing!